# How does cache work when MySQL is remote?

Tags: mysql, nginx, php-5.6, mysql-5.7

I have been working on the server migration of a legacy ecommerce application using PHP 5.6.
The switch involved two Dedicated 32 servers from Linode.
One server is for NginX + PHP and the other is for MySQL only.
The legacy application leverages memcached.

After the switch, I can see a heavy internal traffic caused due to private inbound and outbound connections.
So far this element didn't cause any problem on performance.

However, I was under the impression that the queries would be cached on the local machine, and not on the remote.
Because if the query is cached on the remote host, it sill has to transmit the result set over the private network, instead of retrieving from RAM or the local SSD.

**Am I assuming this wrong?**

It may be that I am missing the point where the private inbound traffic is more beneficial for overall performance when compared to a local cache.

Comment: the cache is on the maschiene where the database server resides. the communication is today in gigabit ethernet(on the same server farm), so that speed isn't usually an issue. with 8.0 there are cache strategies for mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/buffering-caching.html

Comment: Thank you for your observation on `gigabit ethernet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a feature called the Query Cache, but this caches query result sets in the mysqld server process, not on the client. If you run the exact same query again after the result has been cached in the Query Cache, it will copy the result from the Query Cache and avoid the cost of running the query again. But this will not avoid the time to transfer the result across the network from mysqld to your PHP application.

Also keep in mind that the [MySQL Query Cache is being deprecated and retired](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-the-query-cache/).

Alternatively, your application may store data from query results in memcached, but typically this would be done by the application code (I know there are UDF's to read and write memcached from MySQL triggers, but this is a bad idea).

If your memcached service is not on the same host as your PHP code, it would result in network transfer *twice*:  Once when querying the data from MySQL the first time, then again transferring the data *into* memcached, then later every time you fetch the cached data *out* of memcached.

PHP also has some features to do in-memory caching, such as [APCu](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php). I don't have any experience with this, and it's not clear from a brief scan of the documentation *where* it stores cached data.

PHP is designed to be a "shared nothing" language. Every PHP request has its own data, and data doesn't normally last until the next request. This is why a cache is typically not kept in PHP memory. Applications rely on either memcached or the database itself, because those will hold data longer than a single PHP request.

If you have a fast enough network, it shouldn't be a high cost to fetch items out of a cache over a network. The performance architects at a past job of mine developed this wisdom:

> *"Remote memory is faster than local storage."*

They meant that if the data is in RAM on a server, then reading it from RAM even with the additional overhead of transferring it across a network is usually better than reading the data from persistent (disk) storage on the local host.

Comment: Great answer. I can dwell on it for the next 20 days. Thank you.

Comment: @user2094178 caching is always a tricky part especially remote caching in memcached .. Questions/problems like: 1) how long can i cache something before the data becomes to old? 2)  How i am going to invalid the cache?

Comment: ... also @user2094178 as Bill mentiones memcached , MySQL innoDB on linux can natively use memcached  -> [InnoDB memcached Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-memcached.html) as some kind of "Query Cache"... On windows you most likely have to compile the plugin yourself..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I wouldn't compare the InnoDB memcached plugin to a cache. It's an interface compatible with the memcached API, but it reads and writes data in InnoDB tables. So it has the overhead of durable data. That is, it's much slower than using an in-memory cache.

Comment: true thats why i place Query Cache in `""` , but when you use PHP to insert in the memcached plugin controled by MySQL you bypass the "overhead" in SQL parsing/optimisation steps and store in memcached and in InnoDB, so in that respect its a bit faster then inserting it with a query.. Also a extra big plus the MySQL memcached plugin handles the validation of the cache so outdated data never be there thats why i called it a "Query Cache". But disk storage speeds can never be compared vs memory storage speeds even the fastest SDD's nowadays is still considerd to be "slow" compared vs RAM speeds

Comment: The InnoDB memcached plugin does not store query results in memcached. I don't think you have a correct understanding of what that plugin does.

Comment: pretty sure i understand it correctly...  *"The InnoDB memcached plugin (daemon_memcached) provides an integrated memcached daemon that automatically stores and retrieves data from InnoDB tables, turning the MySQL server into a fast “key-value store”. Instead of formulating queries in SQL, you can use simple get, set, and incr operations"*  those get and set operations are memcached service read and save functions unless i totally misinterpret this..

Comment: But i have a feeling we are talking past one and other for  some time now as i never said or claimed memcached plugin to store query results ... Maybe because i misused the term "Query Cache" you misinterpreted what i meant if thats the case sorry for causing confusion..